# Base template class data members are not visible in derived template class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, base-class

Consider the following C++ code,

```
template <typename Derived>
struct A
{
    bool usable_;
};

template <typename Derived>
struct B : A< B<Derived> >
{
    void foo()
    {
        usable_ = false;
    }
};

struct C : B<C>
{
    void foo()
    {
        usable_ = true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
}
```

I got compilation error:  In member function `void B<Derived>::foo()`:

> template_inherit.cpp:12: error: 'usable_' was not declared in this
>   scope.

Why is that ? Any good fix ?

Comment: `struct B : A< B<Derived> >` wat.

Comment: @GMan haha CRTP in disguise :)

Answer (score 17):

That's because `usable_` is a non-dependent name, so it is looked up at the time the template is parsed, instead of being looked up at instantiation (when the base class is known).

Unqualified name lookup will not lookup and non-dependent names are never looked up in dependent base classes. You can make the name `usable_` dependent as follows, which will also get rid of unqualified name lookup

```
this->usable_ = false;

// equivalent to: A<B>::usable_ = false;
A< B<Derived> >::usable_ = false;

B::usable_ = false;
```

All of these will work. Or you can declare the name in the derived class with a using-declaration

```
template <typename Derived>
struct B : A< B<Derived> >
{
    using A< B<Derived> >::usable_;

    void foo()
    {
        usable_ = false;
    }
};
```

Note that in `C` there will be no problem - it only affects `B`.

Comment: The last GotW talks about it. Alas, Herb Sutter's usual well-written following solution didn't ensue. :(